# I can't extract time with Beautiful Soup ...why?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

[This is the HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmYw7.jpg)

I need extract the date and time but when I do:

```
html = BeautifulSoup(htmlText, "html.parser")

contenido = html.find('span', {'id': 'hora'}).getText()

print(contenido)
```

Shows nothing in the output but without "getText()" the output is 
`<span id="hora"></span>` without the hour. What can I do? I'm coding in Python.

Comment: You can just edit your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely time is inserted with JS. Try to load the entire page and search for this string using the interpreter. If in time this line will not be - then I'm right. Often the browser and the script see the page differently. If so, you can try Ctrl + Chift + U and look for time in the tab Network. If it is not there, then look for the script on the page.

Look in Network -> XHR. If this hasn't request time, you need use Selenium for parsing this time. Parsers do not support the processing inside the script.

Comment: Yes, the time is inserted with JS. So, how can i extract if it is inserted with JS?

Comment: Look in Network -> XHR. If this hasn't request time, you need use Selenium for parsing this time. Parsers do not support the processing inside the script.

Comment: Definitely i need use Selenium because XHR shows nothing. How can i do that with Selenium? Here is the HTML code:

Comment: Slenium use your browser for parsing, JS work in the browser. Read Selenium Documentation. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/

Answer (score 0):

It's work with selenium! thank you Jrazor!

`hora = driver.find_element_by_class_name("segundaLinea").text`

Now i can get the hour! :)